# how to change the console output without changing the basic input

Tags: javascript

so
theres an code like this

```js
const a = "point1,point2"

console.log(a)
```

the result will be "point1,point2" in the console

the question How do we get that result changed to "point1 / point2" in console

Comment: `console.log(a.replace(',', ' / '))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 100 ways to achieve that:

```
//1 one way    
const a = "point1,point2"
console.log(a.split(',').join('/'))//will output point1/point2

//Another way    
console.log(a.replace(',','/'))//will output point1/point2

//...For the rest learn the basic of javascript and find answers alone
```

Stop running...take your time to learn basic before tackling little projects

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.replace` method to replace `,` by `/`

```js
const a = "point1,point2"

console.log(a.replace(',', '/'));
```

Lear more on [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) here